# Will getServerSideProps be populated if it contains a cached value from an API call?

Tags: caching, next.js

I want to use nextjs for a new project. In this project my frontend is a React application that uses getServerSideProps. Initially my frontend will have nothing to render, because the server side props contain the definition of which UI should be rendered.

Within the server side props I do an API call to fetch the configuration for which UI to render. This request will be stored SERVER SIDE for a long time (24 hours or more).

So my question is: will my initial UI already display something before the hydration if the server side props have a cached value?

Example:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Get data from Cache
  const data = getCachedData('config')
  if(data) {
    return { props: { data } }
  }
  
  // Cache is empty, re-fetch and cache now
  const res = await fetchAndCache(`https://.../data`)
  const data = await res.json()
 
  return { props: { data } }
}
 
export default function Page({ data }) {
  // Render data...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly.

In Next.js, when you use getServerSideProps for fetchin' data on the server side, it allows for an initial client-side render that waits until the data fetchin' process is complete. If a cached value is available and returned within the getServerSideProps function, the initial render will swiftly display content before hydration.

In the example provided:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    // Retrieve data from Cache
    const cachedData = getCachedData('config');
    if (cachedData) {
        return { props: { data: cachedData } };
    }

    // Cache is empty, initiate re-fetch and caching process
    const response = await fetchAndCache(`https://.../data`);
    const fetchedData = await response.json();

    return { props: { data: fetchedData } };
}

export default function Page({ data }) {
    // Render data...
}
```

If getCachedData('config') brings back a cached value, it will be used in the initial render. In situations where the cache is empty, an API call will be made to fetch the data, followed by caching.

It's important to note that the synchronous nature of server-side rendering (SSR) in Next.js ensures that the initial render uses cached data if available, facilitating a quick initial load. Subsequent visits within the cache duration will also benefit from the cached data.